# R: Is there a vectorized %in%

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table of stock collections

```
stocks = data.table(date = c('2000-01-01', '2001-01-01'), upStocks = c(list(c('A','B')), list(c('A','C'))), myStock = c('B','B'))

stocks
         date upStocks myStock
1: 2000-01-01      A,B       B
2: 2001-01-01      A,C       B
```

I want to check for every day if my stock is up

```
foreach(i = 1:nrow(stocks), .combine = c) %do% stocks[i, myStock %in% upStocks[[1]]]
[1]  TRUE FALSE
```

Is there a way of not using a loop?

(It's not ok for me to split upStocks into multiple rows, as this table will be rolling joined to another table)

Comment: maybe `stringr::str_match(stocks$upStocks, stocks$myStock)`

Comment: Are you only looking at a single stock, and are there never going to be partial matches to stock IDs? if so, stocks[,BisUp := grepl("B",upStocks)] may do it

Comment: `stocks[, myStock %in% upStocks[[1]], by = date]` would be a data.table solution. However, I'd not organize my data the way you have chosen.

Comment: @Roland, I see. I don't like it as well, but can't think of anything better. What would be the way you prefer?

Comment: If a relational database is not an option, I'd use two long-format data.tables, one for `upStocks` and one for `myStock`. Then you could use a join operation to solve your question.